# How I can draw different marker symbols over each line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How I can draw different marker symbols over each line in the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np



def run(results_directory, optimizer, objectivefunc, Iterations):
    plt.ioff()
    fileResultsData = pd.read_csv(results_directory + "/exp.csv")
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    for j in range(0, len(objectivefunc)):
        objective_name = objectivefunc[j]
        startIteration = 0
        if "SSA" in optimizer:
            startIteration = 1
        allGenerations = [x + 1 for x in range(startIteration, Iterations)]
        for i in range(len(optimizer)):
            optimizer_name = optimizer[i]

            row = fileResultsData[
                (fileResultsData["Optimizer"] == optimizer_name)
                & (fileResultsData["objfname"] == objective_name)
            ]
            row = row.iloc[:, 3 + startIteration :]
            plt.plot(allGenerations, row.values.tolist()[0],linestyle = 'dashed',label=optimizer_name)

        plt.title("Curve")
        plt.xlabel("Iterations")
        plt.ylabel("Fitness")
        plt.yscale("log")
        plt.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1.02))
        plt.grid()
        fig_name = results_directory + "/convergence0-" + objective_name + ".png"
        plt.savefig(fig_name, bbox_inches="tight")
        plt.clf()


p = Path(r"C:\Users\sa\Desktop\C2017")
p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
run(str(p), ["HybridSSALEO","MFO","CSO","SSA",
             "HHO","PSO","SCA","WOA","BAT"],["f1"], 2500)
```

---

sample of data to run the function

```
    Optimizer   objfname    ExecutionTime   Iter1   Iter2   Iter3   Iter4   Iter5   Iter6   Iter7   ... Iter2491    Iter2492    Iter2493    Iter2494    Iter2495    Iter2496    Iter2497    Iter2498    Iter2499    Iter2500
0   HybridSSALEO    f1  7.43    2.580000e+12    2.290000e+12    2.170000e+12    2.050000e+12    1.820000e+12    1.700000e+12    1.650000e+12    ... 2104.890630 2104.880800 2104.874638 2104.868994 2104.863237 2104.857936 2104.853139 2104.849307 2104.843981 2104.829836
1   HybridSSALEO    f2  9.46    5.955520e+10    2.445214e+08    6.004195e+06    5.798884e+06    2.734759e+06    2.633134e+06    1.713644e+06    ... 375.136389  375.017438  374.943893  374.869639  374.687064  374.602179  374.544733  374.447893  374.358422  374.317267
2   HybridSSALEO    f3  14.09   1.516994e+09    2.770653e+05    2.728020e+05    2.684405e+05    2.169289e+05    2.123749e+05    2.080267e+05    ... 440.787196  440.777427  440.772892  440.748491  440.711001  440.698250  440.683562  440.677350  440.676047  440.668172
3   HybridSSALEO    f4  12.08   2.826890e+03    2.549340e+03    2.452620e+03    1.579159e+03    1.558178e+03    1.477120e+03    1.458300e+03    ... 788.193094  788.193094  788.193094  788.193094  788.193094  788.193094  788.193094  788.193094  788.193094  788.193094
4   HybridSSALEO    f5  21.16   8.074877e+02    8.014014e+02    7.957303e+02    7.931306e+02    7.913393e+02    7.872639e+02    7.811320e+02    ... 679.420922  679.420593  679.420393  679.420133  679.419760  679.419323  679.419027  679.418699  679.418348  679.417955
5 rows × 2503 columns
```

I`ve 9 dashed lines with different colors, I hope if anyone can give me tips to change the line style or how to draw different shapes over each of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should loop over each row, and the following code.

```py
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(10):
    ax.plot(x, y + (i / 2), marker=MarkerStyle.filled_markers[i], label=f'label{i}')

ax.legend(loc="upper left")
```

[image]

`MarkerStyle.filled_markers` has 16 marker styles. If you only need nine marker styles, it's okay.

if you want to change line style

```py
{
 '-': '_draw_solid',
 '--': '_draw_dashed',
 '-.': '_draw_dash_dot',
 ':': '_draw_dotted',
 'None': '_draw_nothing',
 ' ': '_draw_nothing',
 '': '_draw_nothing'
}

# from 
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
Line2D.lineStyles
```

example:

```py
for i in range(0, 4):
    ax.plot(x,
            y + (i / 2),
            linestyle=list(Line2D.lineStyles.keys())[i],
            marker=MarkerStyle.filled_markers[i],
            label="Line " + str(i))
```

[image]

[Reference LineStyle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle)

[Reference MarkerStyle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.html#matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle)